# making rails submit form_with through AJAX on keypress

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, onchange, keypress

I'm trying to build a kind of calculator with rails 5.2.
I need to update results fields while I'm writing my input fields. Everything is working perfect with AJAX if I press enter Key on my keyboard but it doesn't work if I try to automaticly submit the form as soon as a field is modified.

the view input.html.erb

```
<%= form_with url: achatproprietaire_output_path do |form| %>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <%= form.label :credits_conso, "Montant des crédits conso", for:"example-helping" %>
        <%= form.text_field :credits_conso, id: "example-helping", placeholder: "crédits conso", class: "form-control", id: "crédit_conso" %>
        <span class="help-block"><small>en euros par mois</small></span>
    </div>
```

js file calles un application.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#crédit_conso").keypress(function(){
    //this.form.trigger('submit.rails');
    Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
  });
});
```

js.erb file correctly called with enter key

```
$('#output_col').replaceWith("<%= j render 'output', capacité_emprunt_maximal: @capacité_emprunt_maximal,
    montant_mensuel_maximal: @montant_mensuel_maximal,
    taux_interet: @taux_interet,
    taux_assurance: @taux_assurance %>");
```

And I have no render or redirect_to in my controller.

I've also tried to put onchange: "Rails.fire(this.form, 'submit')" in the form fields but it submit the form without AJAX.

Comment: Looks like you have several questions in one: could separate them please ?
Also, what do you mean by "it doesn't work": is the request sent or not ? If it is, do you get an error message ?

Comment: ok so, my question is : why when I submit my form with jQuery .submit() function, the request reloads my entire view and is not going through rails AJAX ?

Comment: Hi again !
It's been few months and I just had the same issue on another website. And I still don't know how to make an AJAX call by submitting a form with JS,
If someone is here I would appreciate some help ...
Thanks

Comment: Sorry: my point was that to get answers on StackOverFlow (not just my lousy comments !), you need to ask differently: by asking one question at a time and posting your errors messages. That way, lots of people can give you answers !

Comment: I resolved my problem using jQuery. Here is the code that work nice on my form with ID searchform.

`$("#searchform").keyup(function(e) {
   $("#searchform").submit();
});`

This is correctly firing the submit request through AJAX. And I get my calculation results without page reload

I hope this will help.